# Discord.JS Ping Edit Command

Tags: discord.js

Alright so basically, I am trying to make a command where the author sends !ping, The bot responds with Pinging and then edits it to Pong goes to the next line and then says how many ms it took to respond. Now the problem is when I const the message it is about to send and edit it, It says editing that variable is not a function when I add await to the const it says that only works with async[image: Image of code]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't use an image to show us your code. The StackOverflow editor has great tools to display your code, please use them :)

Comment: `send` returns a promise, you need to either use the `.then` callback, or use the `async/await` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go bud:

```js
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {

    if (oldMessage.content === 'Pinging...') {

        var oldMessageTimestamp = oldMessage.createdTimestamp;
        var newMessageTimestamp = newMessage.editedTimestamp;

        newMessage.edit(`Pong!\nPonged back the ping in ${Math.floor(newMessageTimestamp - oldMessageTimestamp)} milliseconds!`);
    }
});

client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.content === `${prefix}` + `ping`) {

        message.channel.send('Pinging...').then(message => {

            message.edit('Pong!\nPonged back the ping in milliseconds!');
        })
    }
});
```

I believe your error lied in a few things, one you were trying to edit a constant variable, and two you were trying to use the .edit method on a variable, not only that but you were trying to do math on creation dates instead of creation timestamps which wouldn't have worked at all, you have to see the time between creation timestamp and the edit timestamp instead.